# The file prerender-manifest.json is missing or cannot be found in the specified directory

Tags: reactjs, frontend

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend.next\prerender-manifest.json'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\.next\prerender-manifest.json'
}

when given npm run build this errors coming
Generating static pages (0/21)  [=   ]TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(0 , l.useSession)(...)' as it is undefined.
at i (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend.next\server\pages\admin\AdminToCart.js:1:1450)
at Wc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at $c (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
at bd (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)

Error occurred prerendering page "/admin/AdminToCart". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(0 , l.useSession)(...)' as it is undefined.
at i (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend.next\server\pages\admin\AdminToCart.js:1:1450)
at Wc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at $c (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
at bd (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(0 , l.useSession)(...)' as it is undefined.
at i (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend.next\server\pages\admin\contacts.js:1:1445)
at Wc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at $c (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
at bd (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)

Error occurred prerendering page "/admin/dashboard". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(0 , l.useSession)(...)' as it is undefined.
at i (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend.next\server\pages\admin\contacts.js:1:1445)
at Wc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at $c (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
at bd (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(0 , l.useSession)(...)' as it is undefined.
at i (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend.next\server\pages\admin\contacts.js:1:1445)
at Wc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at $c (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
at bd (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)

Error occurred prerendering page "/admin/contacts". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(0 , l.useSession)(...)' as it is undefined.
at i (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend.next\server\pages\admin\contacts.js:1:1445)
at Wc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at $c (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
at bd (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(0 , l.useSession)(...)' as it is undefined.
at i (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend.next\server\pages\admin\orders.js:1:1441)
at Wc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at $c (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
at bd (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)

Error occurred prerendering page "/admin/orders". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(0 , l.useSession)(...)' as it is undefined.
at i (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend.next\server\pages\admin\orders.js:1:1441)
at Wc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at $c (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
at bd (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
at Z (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
at Zc (C:\Users\indipa\Desktop\new\pharmecy_sales_system_frontend\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481)
✓ Generating static pages (21/21)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
> /admin/AdminToCart
> /admin/contacts
> /admin/dashboard
> /admin/orders

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.